# jQuery Fetch/Display data to dropdown when an id or data is selected on edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fetch the data into my dropdown when I edit an id or data, right now the value that is being fetched is null or none of the options that I have in my dropdown. Kindly help on how can I fetch the data using jquery / javascript.

So my final output should be, **when I choose an ID, the value of the dropdown should be displayed**

here is my html code below, I have the dropdown input

```
<select id="position" name="position" class="form-control">
    <option>Select Role</option>
    <option value="Admin" data-id="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="Staff" data-id="2">Staff</option>
</select>
```

here is my script code below,which I use to choose an id to edit or view

```
variable I declare
var position = $('input[name=position]');
```

my ajax code

```
 success: function(data){
  $('input[name=position]').val(data.position); // here is the value from the dropdown
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't selecting the `<select>` element, your selector should be

```
$('select[name=position]').val(data.position);
```

Your original selector was looking for an `<input>` tag, while you might consider a `<select>` as an input control the selectors operate on the tag name which is `select`

Comment: good day sir, thank you for you answer but the output of your code made my dropdown blank, my current code shows the first option which is **Select Role**, I need to fetch the current data of the selected id that I will choose, which is either **Admin** or  **Staff**.

Comment: What does `data.position` contain?

Comment: it contains the value of **Admin** or **Staff** this is the `data.position` - `<select id="position" name="position"` which calls the dropdown to identify its data/

Comment: Do a `console.log(data.position);` to be sure

Comment: I'm suprised, it says `undefined` sir

Comment: do you have a solution sir? I still cant figure it out why it is not fetching the data

Comment: console.log the data in whole and see what that’s returning. Perhaps position isn’t even in data itself.

Comment: @Cue - hello sir, this is what it prints out when i console the whole data `{id: "54", role_id: "2", name: "Mozart", email: "mozart@test.com", position: "Staff", …}`

Comment: @Cue - still the dropdown is fixed on the **Select Role** option. it does not display **Staff** which `id:54` has